# Design pattern that implements draw and setup function in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

To start a p5.js or processing sketch we do this

```
setup() {
   // do setup
}

draw() {
   // draw each frame
}
```

How does this work in p5 js. Is there a thread in the background that calls these functions? I'm having trouble understanding how these methods get called. Is this a design pattern? If so, what would this be called?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

it's just the observer pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern setup and draw are event listeners. setup is called once and draw is called at regular time intervals.

it's not different than `document.onload=function setup(){}` and `setInterval(function draw(){},500)` in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded, so it's not another thread.

Basically, the P5.js library contains some code that automatically calls these functions (and functions like `keyPressed()` and `mouseMoved()`) at the right times. It calls `setup()` when the library is loaded, and it calls `draw()` 60 times per second.

Speaking generally, this is called a **render loop**. Google "render loop" for a ton of resources on how this is handled by different languages and libraries.

P5.js is open-source, so you can look at exactly how it's done [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js). The magic happens inside `main.js`.

Taking a step back, in JavaScript you can call the `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` functions to call a function after a certain amount of time has elapsed. P5.js probably does something like this behind the scenes.